# Only allow selection of one radiobuttonlist

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have 3 different radiobuttonlists on a page, I only want the user to be able to choose one selection from one of the 3 different radiobuttonlists. Is this possible?

Comment: If you want just one item selected, why have three lists? You can use the value to distinguish the sets.

Comment: I think you're thinking that you need three different radio button groups because you need some kind of separate grouping, but you can group a single list into three different visual groups, that allows only one item to be selected.

Comment: Yes the items are grouped into 2 main categories, like this...

Battery Driven Cars - Gasoline driven cars

And then there are subcategories for each type of car

And

Comment: @Erik would you mind give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: I mean you can have your entire list of 9 items in one radio button group, and then you can put each radio button anywhere you want, such as within 3 groups of fieldsets, each with 3 of the radio buttons.  But they're still one big set of 9 buttons as far as the browser is concerned, even though they look like 3 separate groups.

Comment: I just realized you mean the actual RadioButtonList webform control.  If I were you, I would just use a normal set of radio buttons, and do what I say, not use the RadioButtonList control.

Comment: Allrgiht, I'll have to create x number of radiobuttons then from code behind and group them accordingly.